# How to overcome limitation for Config Map in case of fargate logging in AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

I have already setup fargate logging for my EKS cluster pods. Now I have added various other namespaces for aws adot collector pods. When I am trying to apply my terraform configuration it gives me error of

```
│ Error: Failed to update Config Map: admission webhook "0500-amazon-eks-fargate-configmaps-admission.amazonaws.com" denied the request: Config map has too many chars.
```

How do I overcome this config map character limitation.

In the docs also there is mention of 5300 character limitation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html

Here is my configuration

fargate_logging.tf

```
resource "kubernetes_config_map" "fargate_logging" {
  metadata {
    name      = "aws-logging"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.aws_observability.id
  }

  data = {
    #######################################
    # Note: If you change this configuration,
    # consider to recreate pods in buildspec.yml after `terraform apply`.
    # Because Amazon EKS Fargate logging doesn't support dynamic configuration of ConfigMaps.
    # Any changes to ConfigMaps are applied to new pods only.
    # Changes aren't applied to existing pods.
    # refs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-logging.html#fargate-logging-log-router-configuration
    #######################################

    flb_log_cw = "true"

    "parsers.conf" = local.config["parsers_conf"]
    "filters.conf" = local.config["filters_conf"]
    "output.conf"  = local.config["output_conf"]
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_cloudwatch_log_group.fluent_bit_process
  ]
}

locals {
  config = {
    parsers_conf = file("${path.module}/conf/parsers.conf")
    filters_conf = file("${path.module}/conf/filters.conf")
    output_conf = templatefile("${path.module}/conf/output.conf.tmpl",
      {
        xxxxx_region = var.xxxxxx_region_name
        monitoring_region       = var.monitoring_region_name

        namespace_variables = [for ns in local.namespaces : {
          namespace                         = ns
          cloudwatch_log_group_name         = aws_cloudwatch_log_group.fluent_bit_output[ns].name
          cloudwatch_log_stream_name_prefix = join("-", [var.cloudwatch_log_stream_name_prefix, ns, ""])
          firehose_delivery_stream_name     = module.kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream_per_namespace[ns].firehose_delivery_stream_name
          ingest_role_arn                   = var.ingest_role_arn
        }]
      }
    )
  }
}

locals {
  namespaces = ["xxxx", "kube-system","cert-manager","opentelemetry-operator-system","adot-collector",local.logging_namespace]
}
```

output.conf

```
 %{ for var in namespace_variables }
    [OUTPUT]
        Name                  cloudwatch
        Match                 kube.var.log.containers.*_${var.namespace}_*.log
        region                ${monitoring_region}
        log_group_name        ${var.cloudwatch_log_group_name}
        log_stream_prefix     ${var.cloudwatch_log_stream_name_prefix}
        role_arn              ${var.ingest_role_arn}
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            firehose
        Match           kube.var.log.containers.*_${var.namespace}_*.log
        region          ${xxxxxxxxx}
        delivery_stream ${var.firehose_delivery_stream_name}
    %{ endfor ~}
```